# How to check if python is installed in windows from java?

Tags: java, python, installation

How can I check from inside a java program if python is installed in windows?
Python does not add its path to the system Path and no assumption is to be made about the probable path of installation(i.e it can be installed anywhere).

Comment: If Python is not on the System path, how will *anyone* ever find it?  What are you asking for?  A complete filesystem search for Python.exe?

Comment: The python path does not get added to the system path on windows(Needs to be done manually). I was wondering if there is a way to find out without python being there on the system path.(Other than a complete filesystem search.)

Comment: If it's not on the path, and there are no "assumptions" to be made, then your choices are magic and full filesystem search.

Comment: In that case my question is answered.

Comment: I'm still vague on this: What does "installed" means when Python is not on the PATH and cannot be run?

Comment: Python in Windows doesnt add itself to the path(i.e you cannot call python from the command line). The editors ask for the location of the python interpreter.

Comment: I really wish python did a better job of this. The reasoning is you might have multiple python's (python26, python27, python32) installed. (And thus default install is c:\python27\python.exe, etc). But the installer could put a python26.exe, python27.exe, python32.exe into the path that knows where it's respective python.exe is installed and do the right thing. Alternative to that, they could put something in the registry or some other static location to tell you where a particular major/minor version of python is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Java Runtime to exec the following command "python --version".

If it works, you have Python, and the standard output is the version number.

If it doesn't work, you don't have Python.

Comment: The OP states that "Python does not add its path to the system Path", so how would this work?

Comment: If you can't execute `python`, then it isn't really "installed" is it?

Comment: @S.Lott : I installed python from net many times on my window 7 machine but when I opened the cmd prompt & typed python it never worked. Finally when I included the path in my "PATH" variable then only it started working. Probably the msi installer should do the editing of the path as well for it work automatically for any user.

Comment: IMHO, if python is installed in a customized path, and some shell rc file must be sourced to get the path into `PATH`. Then this test will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Most Python installers add keys to the Windows registry.  Here's [an article](http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm) about how to add that information, you can use it to see how to read the information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried querying the registry to check if it is installed? It is stored in

`software\python\pythoncore`

If the user has a (relatively) new version of python, that is installed with the MSI-package, you can use the [MsiEnumProducts Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370101%28VS.85%29.aspx) to check if python is installed.

Comment: Ya thats one way. But will the registry be upto date?

Comment: IIRC,  Python can be installed in a "no registry updates" mode.

Answer (score 0):

exec(String command) 
          Executes the specified string command in a separate process.
Check for Python from command

Comment: The OP states that "Python does not add its path to the system Path", so how would this work?

Comment: hey noo,
it must be on PATH in windows atleast!

Answer (score -2):

this would work

- Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c
  C:\Python27\python --version");

Comment: Ya thats one way.  But did the user install exactly that version of python or even use pythons default folder when installing?